# FTPWebRequest behind NAT (PASV,SSL)

Tags: .net, networking, ssl, ftpwebrequest, ftps

Has anyone successfully used the .Net FTPWebRequest class to ftps to a remote server from behind a NAT?  My code is as follows:

```
 Dim URI = "ftp://" & sRemoteDir & "/"
    Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest = Nothing
  Try
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate
   ftp = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
   ftp.CachePolicy = New System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)
   ftp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUID, sPw)
   ftp.EnableSsl = True
   ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

   Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
   Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
   Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
   Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
   sb.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd)
   streamReader.Close()
   response.Close()
   Return sb.ToString()
  Catch ex As Exception
   Return (ex.Message)
  End Try
```

And I get the following exception:

> "Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond."

I know the code is good, as it works if the machine is not behind a NAT.  Any ideas?  The machine has a static IP and all ports are open for traffic to/from the specified host.

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337673/can-explicity-ftps-via-filezilla-but-not-from-code

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without knowing your firewall or ftp server set up, but at a guess - you need to look at how the server is set up to use passive mode.
I'm most familar with using filezilla, they have a pretty good explanation on network configurations [here](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) and an example of how their server/client software need to be set up...